# A simple database for an HTA

Tags: javascript, hta

I have been tasked with creating a couple of databases for local use in our office, one for logging sickness calls and another for logging staff taxis.

I do not have the ability to install new software on the machines that will be used to develop the app nor on the machines that will use the app, so no xAMP based application, unfortunately. Excel is available, but I'd rather not go down that route as I want to provide a clean UI.

So I'm looking at putting together an HTA based application. The question is: I cannot seem to find a simple, easy to use database-type storage solution for an HTA application. Do I need to write something from scratch, or can anyone recommend something I can use?

Answer (score 3):

You can try an [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) ActiveX wrapper, like [SQLite COM](http://www.newobjects.com/product.asp?Category=71) or [SqLite2X](http://dimzon541.narod.ru/sqlitex/).

Comment: That was the route I was originally going to go down, but the COM object didn't seem to want to load, I don't know if that is due to a security setting or not. I'm investigating as we speak...

Answer (score 3):

If you can't install anything...

- You should be able to connect to a ... **dun dun dunnnn** ... Access database using `ADODB.Connection` - [VBScript example here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/HTML/DBTool.aspx), but the API should be portable to JScript, e.g. http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2005/7/14/13942/7643
- Quick and dirty idea - store everything in a JavaScript `Object` and read/write JSON to/from a file.

Comment: I was considering both of those options, but:

1. I cannot really use an Access DB as we don't have Access installed. (That, and Access sucks...)

2. Yeah, pretty much my other idea, the only problem with that is how fast the file will grow. Performance could be an issue (The machines here aren't exactly modern!) if I start trying to parse 5 or 6 Mb text files. But this is still an option...

Kai.

Comment: You don't need to have Access installed to use ADO, it comes built-in on all versions Windows (since 98 if I recall correctly). Use the ADOX library to create a database. SQLite would be my first choice though so I'd keep working on that. Also, build yourself a 10MB test JSON file and see how long it really takes. It might be reasonable. But will your system have multiple simultaneous users? A text file database will not handle that well, and an MDB file will have limitations as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use XML, with smthn like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762708%28VS.85%29.aspx

but in my opinion, MDB(msaccess database) is the best way:

- no external requirements in xp,vista,sevent and 8
- it is a real DB (triggers,indexes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Ragic](http://www.ragic.com/), instead of writing something from scratch. You really don't have to code anything, and your coworkers wouldn't be too perplexed, as it uses a spreadsheet interface like Excel. Also, it's a cloud database on the web, so you won't have to install on the office computers.